# Displaying Html tags in c# label

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Im using C# through Visual Studio 2017. 
I have a string like this `"<b>Hello!</b> <i>World</i>"` and I want to pass it to a label.Text to display it like this **Hello!** *World*. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the web browser control. Than you can inject html code directly:

```cs
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<b>Hello!</b> <i>World</i>";
```

Or look at this project:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32376/A-Professional-HTML-Renderer-You-Will-Use